# Broken TYPO3 installation on Linux Ubuntu. What to do now?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have installed TYPO3 on my Linux Ubuntu.
TYPO3 is version 11.5.4.

When I want to install TYPO3 CMS, errors like below shows up.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to start over, delete all files in your document root and all tables in the database. But beware, you will loose everything!

But most probably it's not necessary. First of all you should set `display_errors` to 1 in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` (don't forget to turn it off again once you found the error!). With display errors on, you should get a more verbose error message once you call frontend or TYPO3 backend.

Next you should check the error log in `YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/var/log` (composer based installation) or `typo3temp/var/log/` (classic installation).

If your really want to start from scratch, I recommend to follow the [installation guidelines](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/Install.html#install) from the official TYPO3 documentation.

Maybe it's easier to start with a TYPO3 installation on your local machine. Here is a good documentation to [get started with DDEV](https://typo3.com/blog/tutorial-get-a-local-typo3-v10-installation-with-no-effort).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does insllation with DDEV works also for TYPO3 v11?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just change `ddev composer create typo3/cms-base-distribution:"dev-master" --prefer-dist` to `ddev composer create typo3/cms-base-distribution:"^11" --prefer-dist`

Comment: I installed via composer (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/Installation/Install.html#install). Now I have in my /var/www/html/example-project-directory all the files (composer.jsoon, .lock, config file, public file,..) than next step is just access TYPO3 via web browser.. how can I do that?

Comment: You need to configure your webserver to point the document root to the `public` folder of your installation.

Comment: Please check my edited question. I have new error

Comment: Well, the error message is quite obvious and you could have googled that yourself. The database credentials are either wrong or missing. You can check that in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`.